# How to edit Excel 2011 VBA buttons instead of clicking them

Tags: excel, vba, macos

When I click the VBA buttons in Excel 2007 I go to edit mode. But when I'm trying to modify them inExcel 2011 - I click it, and it clicks! But how to switch command mode and edit mode?

Comment: Normally you can just right click on the button to get it into a designy state where you can move it and resize it etc...

Answer (score 8):

Excel 2011 doesn't support ActiveX Controls. It only supports Form Controls. And to access the code area you may follow any of the following steps

1. Right Click on the form button, then on `Assign Macro`. In the next dialog box, Click on `New`
2. Press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to access the VBA Editor. Create a sub in a module and then link it to the form button using `Assign Macro` as mentioned above
3. Click on the Excel Menu next to the Apple Icon, and then click on Preferences. Click on `Ribbon` in `Sharing and Privacy` and then select the Developer checkbox.

**ScreenShot**:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to first make sure you have the developer tools added to the ribbon: 
Select File, Options, then select Customize Ribbon and make sure the "Developer" tab is selected. Click Ok.
Then you can go to the Developer ribbon tab and select "Design Mode" This will let you edit things and will change the button behaviour so that double clicking will open associated code.

Comment: But where is it in Excel 2011? There only buttons: Editor, Macros, Record, etc.

Comment: oh are we talking about Excel for Mac 2011?